# Disable public function in WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, overwrite

I am using the Woocommerce Admin Custom Order Fields plugin which is causing issues when searching orders in the backend. When I run a slow query on the admin order search function it searches through these custom fields and adds 10secs or so to the search.

I have found the function that does it with the plugin and I'm trying to work out the best way to disable the custom fields being included in the search.

When I comment out this code the search is quick, a couple of seconds. I want to add an override or disable it somehow in my functions.php

```
public function add_search_fields( $search_fields ) {

    foreach ( wc_admin_custom_order_fields()->get_order_fields() as $order_field ) {

        if ( 'date' === $order_field->type  ) {
            array_push( $search_fields, $order_field->get_meta_key() . '_formatted' );
        } else {
            array_push( $search_fields, $order_field->get_meta_key() );
        }
    }

    return $search_fields;
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to stop this executing without editing the plugin files directly?
Cheers
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't comment all the function code, but just the active code inside the function, like:

```
public function add_search_fields( $search_fields ) {
    /* 
    foreach ( wc_admin_custom_order_fields()->get_order_fields() as $order_field ) {

        /* if ( 'date' === $order_field->type  ) {
            array_push( $search_fields, $order_field->get_meta_key() . '_formatted' );
        } else {
            array_push( $search_fields, $order_field->get_meta_key() );
        }
    }
    */  
    return $search_fields;
}
```

Now this function will not have any effect, as it's active code is commented.

Now **overwriting any core plugin code is really something to avoid**… There are always different ways to change things, like using available hooks and other things may be more complicated…

Comment: Would this be a complex thing to disable via functions.php?

Comment: @Nik Yes it could be… Now If I remember this plugin mechanic for each custom field you can set multiple behaviors …Check that the field option "Allow Filtering on View Orders screen" is not enabled for each field. Now the best way should be removing this plugin and coding instead all required the custom fields. It will lighten everything.

Comment: They do have a Display in View Orders screen option but even when that is removed it is included in the search. Seems your option of custom solution makes the best sense.